# Create a CSV file and upload it to AWS S3 bucket from lambda function

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a CSV file in an AWS s3 bucket. When the CSV file arrives in a Lambda function the function gets triggered. What I want to do is, I want to remove some special characters from the CSV file and again stores it to another S3 bucket.

In my Lambda function, I can receive the file from the S3 bucket and can read the file from the S3 object content.

```
S3Object s3Object = this.s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(srcBucket, srcKey));
InputStream objectData = s3Object.getObjectContent();   
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(objectData));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if(line.contains("\"")) {
            String newLine= line.replace("\"", "");
        }
    }
```

After removing the character how can I write the file and store the file into another S3 bucket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to manipulate Amazon S3 files in AWS Lambda functions is:

- Copy the file from S3 to local `/tmp`
- Manipulate/edit the file
- Upload the file to S3

The relevant commands are:

- `GetObject()`
- `PutObject`

For example:

```
s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, 
        new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\testvideo.mp4")));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have copy of the file in /tmp and I have also edited it. But I dont know how to use PutOject method. How can I create a s3 object from the tmp file? Do you have some sample code?

Comment: There are plenty of [examples on the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+putobject+s3). I've added on to my answer.